# How to pass a value from view model to model?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm programming a project about securities. Data object includes 5 properties: symbol, price, change, change percentage and quantity. But table of data only have 4 column, because the column "Change" include "change" and "change percentage" by clicking.
I set 2 bool var: IsVisibleChange and IsVisibleChangePct in object to decide alternate appering of "Change" and "ChangePct".
So I need how to pass a pass a value from viewmodel to model. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you need to do,but there's a way to pass values:

[MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

1.**Publish a message** by `MessagingCenter.Send`

2.**Subscribe to a message** by `MessagingCenter.Subscribe`