# Pass value from ViewModel in one project into property located in another project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have property SettingValue in `SettingsViewModel.cs` located in project `ExampleApp` that I would like to use as setting and in case it changes, I would like to pass it as a property (DeviceName) into another Class named `ServiceOne.cs` that is located in another project `ExampleApp.Service`.

I would like to know solution without using MessagingCenter. MessagingCenter is available only for Xamarin. I want to understand how this should be done in general so I can utilize it also for example in WPF and other.

According to my research I need to create a new project with interface and use it for passing value from `SettingsViewModel.cs` to `ServiceOne.cs`? However I cant figure out how it can be done. Any hints?

**SettingsViewModel.cs:**

```
using ExampleApp.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace ExampleApp.ViewModels
{
  public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public SettingsViewModel()
    {
      Title = "Browse";
    }

    private string settingValue;
    public string SettingValue
    {
      get => this.settingValue;
      set
      {
        this.settingValue = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**ServiceOne.cs:**

```
namespace ExampleApp.Service
{
  public class ServiceOne
  {
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    private void OnDeviceDiscovered()
    {
      this.DeviceName = "";
    }
  }
}
```

Please notice also project references.

[image]

Comment: Full example can be found here: https://github.com/vadimffe/ExampleApp

Comment: I'd use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a value from view model to model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57392552/how-to-pass-a-value-from-view-model-to-model).  Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/68835479/199364. Bottom line: it doesn't matter that they are different projects. Except one detail: You need to reference a class that is accessible by both projects, in Publish/Subscribe.

Comment: So `ExampleApp` can not have `ExampleApp.Services` (or `.dll`) in its dependencies? I think there must be a dependency either direct or indirect..

Comment: @MuhammadSulaiman that would be easy with references. However this is not an option as I can't add reference thee other way as it would cause circular reference.

Comment: If you can't reference a project you can create a third project with necessary classes and link both your projects to it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on how and where you instantiate `SettingsViewModel` and `ServiceOne` classes.
The simplest case is when the `SettingsViewModel` creates an instance of `ServiceOne`.

```cs
    private readonly ServiceOne serviceOne = new();
    public string SettingValue
    {
      get => serviceOne.DeviceName;
      set
      {
        serviceOne.DeviceName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
```

Very often, such instances are created at higher levels (for example, in App). In this case, you need to inject dependencies.

```cs
  public class SettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
  {
    public SettingsViewModel(ServiceOne serviceOne)
    {
      Title = "Browse";
      this.serviceOne = serviceOne ?? ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceOne));
    }

    private readonly ServiceOne serviceOne;
    public string SettingValue
    {
      get => serviceOne.DeviceName;
      set
      {
        serviceOne.DeviceName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }
  }
```

Somewhere in App.Startup:

```cs
    ServiceOne serviceOne = new(); // Save in field
    SettingsViewModel settingsVM = new(serviceOne);
```